# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre ++a y a++ dentro de un bucle for en C?

Tags: c, bucle-for

Entiendo como funcionan los operadores de postincremento `++A` y preincremento `A++` y cuando se deben usar pero no comprendo cual es la diferencia al usarlo en la estructura de un `for` en lenguaje C

```
for(A = 1; A <= 10; ++A)
```

o

```
 for(A = 1; A <= 10; A++)
```

¿Cual es la diferencia ya que veo que corre igual?

Comment: Te he sugerido una edición

Answer (score 1):

En este caso, ambos hacen lo mismo.

Si en cambio, estuvieras haciendo una asignación, la diferencia sería así:

El **postincremento**, hace la asignación primero y luego el incremento.

```cpp
int b = 1;
int a = b++;
// a = 1
// b = 2
```

El **preincremento**, hace el incremento primero y luego la asignación.

```cpp
int b = 1;
int a = ++b;
// a = 2
// b = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo que pones no hay diferencia dado que la evaluación de la condición no se hace al tiempo con el incremento. La última parte del encabezado de un ciclo for, donde usualmente se pone el incremento, se evalúa después del cuerpo y antes de la condición.

Sería diferente si se usara un incremento dentro de la condición. Por ejemplo:

```c
for (int i = 1; i++ <= 10; )
{
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

// Salida (10 líneas del 2 al 11):
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
// 10
// 11
```

```c
for (int i = 1; ++i <= 10; )
{
    printf("%i\n", i);
}

// Salida (9 líneas del 2 al 10):
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
// 10
```

Estas formas de usar un ciclo for no son comunes y, en general, resultan extrañas. Solo me parecen útiles para ilustrar la forma en que se ejecutan cada una de las partes.

Hay que aclarar que en la pregunta están invertidos los nombres porque postincremento correspondería `i++` y preincremento a `++i`.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes ver la diferencia porque la variable la estas leyendo en ambos casos después de que el incremento sucede, esas dos diferentes formas en que usas el operador se llama notacion prefix y postfix.

## postfix:

```
variable++
```

## prefix:

```
++variable
```

A los operadores que requieren dos valores, en donde el operador queda en medio de ellos se le llama notación `infix`

## infix:

```
 variable1 + variable2
```

Lo siguiente de abajo devuelve 10 como resultado de usar de esa forma el operador mientras que usando numero++ devuelve el numero que la variable tiene actualmente y no al que se ha incrementado, la variable ya ha incrementado y la próxima vez que la uses tendrá el valor al que ha incrementado

```
int numero = 9
++numero
```

En un bucle `for`, siempre que uses la variable en el bloque del cuerpo del bucle estas leyendo el valor al que ha incrementado porque la estas leyendo después de que la operación `++numero` ha sucedido, esa es la razón por la cual no hay ninguna diferencia